# Observable.FromAsyncPattern: parameter passed to BeginInvoke gets nulled

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, system.reactive

I'm trying to use Rx to write an asynchronous DataContext for linq-to-sql on Windows Phone 7.5. My idea is to define a method in the DataContext:

```
IObservable<List<Fact>> GetFacts(Func<MyDataContext, IQueryable<Fact>> selector)
    {
        var selectFacts = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<MyDataContext, IQueryable<Fact>>(selector.BeginInvoke, selector.EndInvoke);
        return selectFacts(db).Select((query) => query.ToList());// db variable is MyDataContext instance, and is not null during the call or later
    }
```

This method should then be called from the client code, like this:

```
var q = GetFacts((database) => from item in database.Facts select item)
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Do((facts) => MessageBox.Show(facts.Count.ToString()))
    .Subscribe();
```

The problem I'm facing is quite strange. When the client selector (`from item in database.Facts select item`) is actually called, the `database` parameter in it's context is null! Therefore, I'm obviously getting the NullReferenceException. But when the `selectFacts` is called, the `db` value is non-null, and points to correct instance.

Are there any explanations to this fact? How to overcome it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going about this in a very strange way. If you want to run code in the background and have it return an `IObservable<T>` (like Task), you should use `Observable.Start`:

```
IObservable<List<Fact>> factsFuture = Observable.Start(
    () => selectFacts(db).Select(query).ToList(), 
    Scheduler.ThreadPoolScheduler);
```

Comment: Okay, never mind, I found out how to do it correctly, and your approach is working. Still wondering what was wrong in mine...